# RoR - Running Production of Application fails to load images from CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application that works fine in development but can not get certain images that are loaded from css files to load. Images that are on the html.erb load fine though.

Here is the string in my css:

```
.greyscale .banner-logo {
    background: url(/assets/theme/greyscale/greyscale_main_logo.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Here is my production.rb (with comments removed):

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

and here is my development.rb (with comments removed):

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

and here is my assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.js/,/.*\.css/]
```

What do I need to add/modify in my production.rb to allow me to view images from css files?

Comment: any error during pre-compilation? what is the browser console throwing up?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue and pointing image this way helped.

```
.greyscale .banner-logo {
    background-image: image-url("theme/greyscale/greyscale_main_logo.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

This way asset pipeline will try to look for the image in `assets/images/theme/grescale` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Change your filename extension to `css.erb` or `scss.erb` depending upon your original file extension. Then you can use

```
background: url("<%= asset_path 'theme/greyscale/greyscale_main_logo.png') %>" no-repeat center center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your css something like this.

```
url(image-path('greyscale_main_logo.png'))
```

image-path is normally used to get the correct path to assets folder. You might have extend the demo above to 'theme/greyscale/grayscale_main_logo...'

Answer (score 0):

That's because the asset pipeline uses digests in the asset filenames to reference your assets in production. To fix this use `asset-path`, or `image-path`:

```
.greyscale .banner-logo {
    background: url(image-path('theme/greyscale/greyscale_main_logo.png')) no-repeat center center;
}
```

This would work for referencing `app/assets/images/greyscale/greyscale_main_logo.png`